# Angular 6 http fetching results status: "ZERO_RESULTS"

Tags: typescript, http, jsonp, angular6, google-geocoding-api

I'm taking a course on angular and the angular version used in the course is angular 2 so I'm having some issues with my code..

I'm supposed to get my location based on the latitude and longitude and by using a google API it will return the location name from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) using reverse geocoding

however, I for some reasons can't get any values with my code .. it's supposed to return an array of locations but the result in the console is:
 {results: Array(0), status: "ZERO_RESULTS"}

the code in file .service.ts

```
   getLocationName(lat:number, long:number):Observable<any>{
    const url = GOOGLE_ROOT;
    const queryParams = "?latlng=" + lat + "," + long + "&key="+ GOOGLE_KEY;

    return this.http.get(url+queryParams)
        .pipe(map(loc =>loc.json()))


}
```

full file of service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Jsonp, Http} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


import {FORCAST_KEY, FORCAST_ROOT, GOOGLE_KEY, GOOGLE_ROOT} from '../constants/constants';



@Injectable()
export class WeatherService{
constructor(private jsonp:Jsonp, private http: Http){}
getCurrentLocation() : Observable<any>{
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos=>{
                observer.next(pos);
            }
        ),
        err => { 
            return Observable.throw(err);}
        });
    }else{
        return Observable.throw("Geolaction is not available");
    }

}

getCurrentWeather(lat:number, long:number): Observable<any>{
    const url= FORCAST_ROOT+FORCAST_KEY+"/"+lat+","+long;
    const queryParams = "?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK";

    return this.jsonp.get(url+queryParams)
    .pipe(map(data=>data.json()))

}



getLocationName(lat:number, long:number):Observable<any>{
    const url = GOOGLE_ROOT;
    const queryParams = "?latlng=" + lat + "," + long + "&key="+ GOOGLE_KEY;

    return this.http.get(url+queryParams)
        .pipe(map(loc =>loc.json()))


}
```

}

and this is the code in file .component.ts

```
getLocationName(){
    this.service.getLocationName(this.pos.coords.latitude, this.pos.coords.longitude)
        .subscribe(location => {
            console.log(location); //TODO: remove
        },error => {
            console.log('Error happened' + error);
        }
    )
}
```

the full file of component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from '../service/weather.service';
import { Weather } from '../model/weather';

@Component({
selector: 'weather-widget',
templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css'],
providers:[WeatherService]
})

export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit{
pos : Position;
WeatherData = new Weather(null, null, null, null, null);
currentSpeedUnit = "kph";
currentTempUnit = "fahrenheit";
currentLocation = "";
constructor(private service:WeatherService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.getCurrentLocation();

}
getCurrentLocation(){
    this.service.getCurrentLocation()
        .subscribe(position => {
            this.pos = position;
            this.getCurrentWeather();
            this.getLocationName();

        },
        err => console.error(err));
}

getCurrentWeather(){
    this.service.getCurrentWeather(this.pos.coords.latitude, this.pos.coords.longitude)
        .subscribe(weather => {
            this.WeatherData.temp = weather["currently"]["temperature"],
            this.WeatherData.summary = weather["currently"]["summary"],
            this.WeatherData.wind = weather["currently"]["windSpeed"],
            this.WeatherData.humidity = weather["currently"]["humidity"],
            this.WeatherData.icon = weather["currently"]["icon"]
            console.log("Weather:", this.WeatherData); //to remove
        },
        err => console.error(err));
}


getLocationName(){
    this.service.getLocationName(this.pos.coords.latitude, this.pos.coords.longitude)
        .subscribe(location => {
            console.log(location); //TODO: remove
        }
    );
}
```

}

I'm still new to angular. I hope someone can help me.
This project  is uploaded in github [here](https://github.com/tahani-alqsj/weather-widget) to see full code

Comment: Is your http call returning with anything ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: in the terminal : ERROR in src/app/weather-widget/service/weather.service.ts(60,33): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
and in console: Error happenedTypeError: loc.json is not a function

Comment: I actually figured out the reason.. in the constructor i had the http to httpclient so changed it to http.. but the result is an empty array .. in the console: {results: Array(0), status: "ZERO_RESULTS"}